# Good SPARQL query to find all triples with a resource as subject or object

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, linked-data

I need to find all triples on DBpedia where http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benin is a subject or object. This query gives me the output that I want in a format that works the best for me (just three variables and no blank spaces):

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT * WHERE {
?s ?p ?o
FILTER (?s=:Benin OR ?o=:Benin)
}
```

I get similar results if I have this query:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT * WHERE {
{:Benin ?p ?o}
UNION
{?s ?p :Benin}
}
```

However, the formatting of the latter is off. It first gives me `p` and `o` output leaving `s` blank and then `s` and `p` leaving `o` blank. Also, the first query takes more time to execute. I will be grateful for an explanation of the mechanics of how the two queries work and why there is a difference in the output.

Comment: `OR` is spelt `||` in SPARQL.

Comment: @AndyS Yes, but the backend virtuoso of dbpedia does not seem to care, albeit I cannot find confirmation for this on the source level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=++++PREFIX+%3A+<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F>%0D%0A++++DESCRIBE++%3ABenin&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) --

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
DESCRIBE  :Benin
```

-- or just --

```
DESCRIBE  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benin>
```

You can get the output in various other serializations, including [N-triples](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A++++DESCRIBE++%3ABenin&format=text%2Fplain&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Comment: This is beautiful :-)

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how one can choose the serialization format?

Comment: Also, this is about DESCRIBE from SPARQL 1.1 official documentation:
"The DESCRIBE form returns a single result RDF graph containing RDF data about resources...The description is determined by the query service." Given this, can we assume that DBpedia furnishes all information about a resource through DESCRIBE (especially when the result has more than 2k triples).

Comment: The public DBpdia endpoint has result set size limits, across all functionality. If you want unlimited results, you will need to pursue [authenticated access](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess), or [get your own instance](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015). `DESCRIBE` output may not exactly match the `SELECT` you started with, for various reasons; followup on this is probably best brought to [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/).

Comment: Serialization format may be chosen through the menu on the SPARQL submission form (currently the most complete list), or with the `&format=` URL argument, or [the `define output:format` pragma](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfcontrollingsparqloutputtypes) within a SPARQL query.

Answer (score 5):

> However, the formatting of the latter is off

That's because both queries have different result sets together with `SELECT *`. The union joins the tuples, but since some tuples are missing parts, you get skewed output.

You can resolve the problem by explicitly listing and selecting the variables:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
   {
       ?s ?p ?o
       FILTER (?s=:Benin)
   }
   UNION 
   {
       ?s ?p ?o .
       FILTER (?o=:Benin)
   }
}
```

Note that this is still much faster on dbpedia than the `OR` filter.

The union will return duplicates when a tuple matches both filter expressions (i.e. `:Benin ?p :Benin`).
`SELECT DISTINCT` would remedy that at additional cost and since it looks like the problem is non-existent, I omitted it for improved performance.

> Also, the first query takes more time to execute.

That's hard to say without the result of an `EXPLAIN()`, but my first guess would be that the equality filter is using the index, while the `OR` filter is using a full table scan. Virtuoso does not [seem to generate good query plans](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716190845/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/19391/sparql-query-performance) for nested filters.